# How to move an element with keys smoothly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    let posLeft = player.style.left;
    let posTop = player.style.top;

    if (e.key === "d") {
      player.style.left = `${parseInt(posLeft) + 10}px`;
    } else if (e.key === "a") {
      player.style.left = `${parseInt(posLeft) - 10}px`;
    } else if (e.key === "w") {
      player.style.top = `${parseInt(posTop) - 10}px`;
    } else if (e.key === "s") {
      player.style.top = `${parseInt(posTop) + 10}px`;
    })
}

document.body.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let posLeft = player.style.left;
  let posTop = player.style.top;
  if (e.code === "Space") {
    const bullet = document.createElement("div");
    gameField.appendChild(bullet);
    bullet.className = "bullet";
    bullet.style.position = "absolute";
    bullet.style.left = `${parseInt(posLeft) + 15}px`;
    bullet.style.top = `${parseInt(posTop) - 10}px`;
  }
});
```

```html
<main class="game-field">
  <h1 class="header">P-P-P</h1>
  <button class="btn-start">START</button>
  <div class="player">
    <img src="plane.png" alt="plane" class="plane" />
  </div>
</main>
```

So I'm trying to build a basic game from scratch just to train myself and sharpen my skills. But I just couldn't figure it out how to move a simple element smoothly. This code actually works but the player has rough movements.

How do I make it move smoothly?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the HTML on which it runs so that answerers can see the rough movements. Please also include what research you've done into the issue and what attempts you've made to solve the issue based on that research.

Comment: you'd want to create a loop that increments the pixel values until you reach your desired value (i.e. 10px). The way you're doing it now, you're instantly chunking to 10px which creates this "rough" sort of movement. And use CSS to apply the animation style, i.e. `translate` property. The translate property might even be enough in itself.

Comment: Added html codes

Comment: Please could you check that your snippet is working?